# SQL Exclude rows previously selected in another category

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Sample ORDER BY Site
```

Output:

```
Site Data
1   Cat
1   Mule
1   Pig
2   Giraffe
2   Dog
2   Horse
2   Mule
4   Cat
8   Dog
8   Pig
8   Mule
8   Bull
9   Bull
9   Giraffe
9   Moose
```

I want to display the Data sorted by Site, but exclude rows that were in a previous Site.
Show all items in Site 1
Any items in Site 2 that were not already shown in Site 1, etc.

So the result show be:

```
Site    Data
----     ----
1   Cat
1   Mule
1   Pig
2   Dog
2   Giraffe
2   Horse
9   Moose
```

The initial list is built from a query with several joins.

A working example would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site = 2
AND Data NOT IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site < 2)
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site = 8
AND Data NOT IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site < 8)
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site = 9
AND Data NOT IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.Sample WHERE Site < 9)
ORDER BY Site
```

My list of Sites comes from a query as well.

SELECT Distinct Site from SiteList

```
1
2
4
8
9
```

Surely there should be an easy and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would give your desired results

```
SELECT MIN(Site) AS Site,
       Data
FROM   dbo.Sample
GROUP  BY Data
ORDER  BY Site
```

Comment: Sweet - Thanks!  I figured there was a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT s.*,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Data Order By Site) 
   FROM dbo.Sample s
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY Site
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.sample a 
WHERE site = 
(SELECT min(site) 
 FROM dbo.sample b 
 WHERE a.data=b.data)
order by site
```

Not as elegant as the first solution, but this will also work if you end up with other columns (like color for instance) with differing values and still only want one row per animal.

Comment: Uses [The “Segment Top” Query Optimisation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT min(site)
FROM dbo.sample
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY 1
```